# scratch resistant matt black paint spray for chrome taps

Tags: spraying, spraypainting

I would like to spray paint some chrome taps and other bathroom fittings matt black. I have seen matt black stove and bbq spray that I have heard is pretty tough and has the matt black effect I want. [stoves online](http://www.stovesonline.co.uk/heat-resistant-spray-paint.html) mentions this spray may need to be heat cured. Are there any other tips, or any other products or approaches that would be better?

Answer (score 1):

The two approaches that might actually work (both rather expensive) are to replace the taps and fittings with factory black ones, or to send the ones you have now out for replating with a black nickel process.

Paint on chrome is a failure that usually does not wait to happen.

I guess there is the option of "Plasti-Dip" - a rubbery spray coating that is commonly used by auto enthusiasts to recolor and/or protect chrome parts - in a somewhat reversible manner (it can be peeled off.) Being rubbery it does not chip, and reports are that it holds up pretty well until deliberately peeled off. Here's a link (no association and I'm not really a fan of the stuff, despite being aware of it.)

http://www.eastwood.com/blog/tech-articles/plasti-dip-faqs-frequently-asked-questions-about-dipping-cars/

Comment: To your list I would add sending the taps away to be powder-coated. They'd probably have to be sandblasted first but a powder-coating shop can do that.